# Can I Create PowerBi report in C# or using macro

Tags: c#, asp.net, macros, excel-2010, office365

Can I create Power Bi report(Office 365) Programmatically in c# or using macro. If yes, How? Please help.
Excel sheet uses Power Query and Power Pivot to create a PowerBi report.Please provide me the link for support of answer so that I can summarize, It can be done or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using macros in excel to manipulate power bi content is not supported.

Lukasz